# Postgres foreign data wrapper query with now()

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to query a remote database using `postgres_fdw` and am having really bad performance degradation when I introduce `now()` into my query.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE
SELECT *
  FROM remote_schema.my_table
 WHERE remote_table.created_at > '2021-03-21';
```

gives the following result:

```
Foreign Scan on remote_schema.my_table  (cost=100.28..297.35 rows=224 width=1727) (actual time=28.460..28.516 rows=220 loops=1)
  Output: id, created_at, column_2, column_3, column_4"
  Remote SQL: SELECT id, created_at, column_2, column_3, column_4 FROM public.my_table WHERE ((created_at > '2021-03-21 00:00:00-07'::timestamp with time zone))"
Planning Time: 0.906 ms
Execution Time: 28.915 ms
```

which is great!

However, if I slightly change the query to use a relative time the performance drops significantly:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE
SELECT *
  FROM remote_schema.remote_table
 WHERE remote_table.created_at > (now() - '3 days'::interval)
```

now gives the much worse result:

```
Foreign Scan on remote_schema.my_table  (cost=100.00..1086.25 rows=216 width=1727) (actual time=18442.738..18443.945 rows=220 loops=1)
  Output: id, created_at, column_2, column_3, column_4"
  Filter: (my_table.created_at > (now() - '3 days'::interval))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 3280
  Remote SQL: SELECT id, created_at, column_2, column_3, column_4 FROM public.my_table"
Planning Time: 0.955 ms
Execution Time: 18444.432 ms
```

It looks like Postgres doesn't realize that the `now() - '3 days'::interval` clause can be be turned into a constant and shipped over to the remote server, and instead thinks it has to bring all of the remote data locally to do the foreign scan.

Is there any way to convince Postgres to be more efficient with the second query?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in a similar StackOverflow post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50167022/237092

The trick is to wrap the `now() - '3 days'::interval` into a subselect, which apparently will convince Postgres to evaluate it first and render the result as a constant to the rest of the query that can then get pushed down to the remote server.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE
SELECT *
  FROM remote_schema.remote_table
 WHERE remote_table.created_at > (SELECT now() - '3 days'::interval)
```

now gives the following excellent performance:

```
Foreign Scan on remote_schema.my_table  (cost=100.31..879.11 rows=1167 width=1727) (actual time=32.002..32.050 rows=220 loops=1)
   Output: my_table.id, my_table.created_at, my_table.column_2, my_table.column_3, my_table.column_4"
   Remote SQL: SELECT id, created_at, column_2, column_3, column_4 FROM public.my_table WHERE ((created_at > $1::timestamp with time zone))"
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=1 loops=1)
          Output: (now() - '3 days'::interval)
Planning Time: 3.938 ms
Execution Time: 32.481 ms
```